# Beast way for create WPF application layout

Tags: wpf, layout

I know how to working layout controls (Grid, StackPanel, DockPanel, etc), but even so, I don't know how to can I combine their for create a good layout.

Has any resource or article talking about this?

Comment: [This is what a Google search gave me.](https://www.google.com/search?q=WPF+application+example+tutorial&oq=WPF+application+example+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5783j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: yeap, I has searched Google, but I found a lot applications with layout so different to default style, I just need some layout more simple, like Windows XP style maybe, I know this is look like simple, but I can't make this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to look this link for a great place to learn layout techniques.

   [WPF & Silverlight Layout Controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/01/14/wpf-silverlight-layout-controls.aspx).

   [Layout Techniques](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/04/layout-techniques-for-windows-forms-developers.aspx).

   It takes an example WinForm dialog and then goes on to making same for WPF.
2. Make layouts for all windows programs like Explorer, Control Panel, Picture viewer, etc. Making more and more common layouts will make you more and more comfortable.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! These two link is so helpful for me!